# Automated Invoices

Tags: extension, email, scheduled-reminders, invoice, automation

I was wondering if there was a way to automate sending invoices. Specifically, I want an invoice to be sent when a membership is expiring in x amount of days.

Currently, I'm thinking about using Message Templates to do this. Consequently, I'd be mimicking an invoice in a Message Template and use tokens to show prices and other info specific to the recipient/member.

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I can offer my experience here. I started off using Scheduled Reminders as an automated invoice and used tokens as you suggest for member specific details for the recipient.
However I found that increasingly organisation would not accept an email based invoice and required an invoice in the form of a PDF attachment, even if the email invoice contained all the required info to make it a tax compliant Invoice.

What I did instead was use the Scheduled Reminders to send out a Renewal Notice which contained a checksum link, so the member then renews the membership on our website page and clicks the option for 'Pay Later' and then an invoice as a PDF attachment is sent to them automatically with their renewal confirmation email.
Hope that may help,
Renaee.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled reminders should provide you the required functionality.

Administer -> Communications -> Schedule Reminder

You should be able to set up the required reminders from there. Hopefully it's pretty self explanatory - however there is more information here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#using-scheduled-reminders-for-memberships